# application not installing on android emulator

Tags: android

I am running tab based application in android.When i try to install the application on the emulator it gives output in the console as

```
[2011-03-08 12:40:35 - TabBar] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2011-03-08 12:40:35 - TabBar] \TabBar\bin\TabBar.apk installed on device
[2011-03-08 12:40:35 - TabBar] Done!
```

Can anyone tell how should i pursue

Thanks in advance
Tushar

Comment: It says..Application is already installed, then what's the problem?

Comment: the application is not showing on android emulator.How should i pursue

Comment: @Tushar: If you know the package name, uninstall it from the console by using the command `adb uninstall <app.package.name>` then try to reinstall it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also tackled with this same problem and finally I found the solution for it. When you creating a new android project using Eclipes and if you didn't create a activity for your first window, your project's Manifest also don't create proper codings for you to application launch up.

So, you should hardcode them yourself.

First check these codes are available or not in your Project's Manifest file, within your main activity tags.

**

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

**

These two code lines are very important. Because these two lines are calling to android OS to launch this app.

So, Make sure these codes are available in your project's Manifest file. If it's not this below Manifest file code will gets you rough idea to fix this problem.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mershanfernando.testingappz"
    android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Main"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```